# AVL tree: Python inheritance issue

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have tree classes: BinarySearchTree, TreeNode and AVLTree.

The TreeNode class is used in BinarySearchTree class. AVLTree inherits BinarySearchTree.See the code below:

```
from Tnode import TreeNode
  class BinarySearchTree:
         def __init__(self):
             self.root = None
             self.size = 0
```

The tree node class looks like this:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent
```

The AVLTree Class:

```
from  Tnode import TreeNode
from binstree import BinarySearchTree

class AVLTree(BinarySearchTree):
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,parent=None,balanceFactor=0):
        TreeNode.__init__(self,key,val,left,right,parent)
        self.balanceFactor = balanceFactor     
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
```

Whenever i run the AVLTree class i get this error:`AttributeError: TreeNode instance has no attribute 'balanceFactor'`

What am i doing wrong?The codes can be viewed here:
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/AVLTreeImplementation.html

http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/SearchTreeImplementation.html

Comment: Why are you calling `TreeNode.__init__` in your `AVLTree.__init__` method, when you don't inherit from `TreeNode` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked over the text you're working off of, I think I see where you've become confused. The change from `BinarySearchTree` to the `AVLTree` classes requires that the `TreeNode` class also be updated (or perhaps a new `AVLTreeNode` class be created) with a new `balanceFactor` attribute. This is never specifically described in the text, and so you've started merging the new stuff that the node needs into the `Tree` class where it is not appropriate.

Instead, put the `balanceFactor` stuff into the an appropriate `Node` class:

```
class AVLTreeNode(TreeNode):
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,parent=None,balanceFactor=0):
        TreeNode.__init__(self,key,val,left,right,parent)
        self.balanceFactor = balanceFactor
```

Now your `AVLTree` code just needs to create `AVLTreeNode` objects instead of `TreeNode` objects, and it will find the appropriate `balanceFactor` attribute when it needs it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I completelly understood your code, but it seems to me that your problem (or at least one of your problems) is in this line `TreeNode.__init__(self,key,val,left,right,parent)`.

I bet you don't want to pass the `self` parameter, as it is of type `AVLTree` and the interpreter is expecting a `TreeNode` type.
Now what I think you might want to do in the `AVLTree` constructor is to simply create a `TreeNode` object to be your AVL root node. To create an instance of a class in Python you don't need to explicitly call the `__init__` method. You can simply do `class_instance = Class(parameters)`, or in your case `self.root = TreeNode(key, val, left, right, parent)`.

So, we can turn what you posted into this: (I will only show what I changed, the remainder of the classes seemed fine to me)

```
class AVLTree(BinarySearchTree):
def __init__(self, key, val, left=None, right=None, parent=None, balancefactor=0):
    self.balanceFactor = balancefactor
    self.root = TreeNode(key, val, left, right, parent)
    self.size = 1
```

We are using the information passed to the tree constructor to create a root node and updating the size of the tree. You can create a simple AVL Tree with a root node with no major problems:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     avl = AVLTree("key", "val")
```

Comment: i did this and it still returns the same error.But I am able to resolve it now.it had few errors somewhere.